# jquery AJAX .done() is executing but not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I have the following two jquery functions.

```
// GET CHAT MESSAGES
let takeDown = true;
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processes/get-chat.php',
    data: 'incoming_id='+incoming_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
      chatBox.html(json.html);
      $("#theStatus").html(json.status);
      $("#typing").html(json.typing);

      if(!chatBox.hasClass("active") && takeDown === true) {
        takeDown = false;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight}, "fast");
      }
    }
  });
}, 500);

// INSERT CHAT MESSAGE
sendBtn.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  var dataString = form.serialize();
  inputField.focus();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processes/chat.php',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
      inputField.val('');
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight}, "fast");
    }
  }).done(function(data){
    if(data.status == 'send'){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'processes/chat-mail.php',
        data: 'name='+data.name+'&email='+data.email+'&msg='+data.message,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Now here the insert chat function inserts the message into the database and get chat function retrieves the messages from the database and displays back to the user. Also the message sent right now is instantly fetched via first function above.

As you can see that the second function uses `.done()` method. This is used to send an email to the other user if he/she is offline. This is working fine. However, this is slowing down the get chat function. The get chat function above is executed only after the `.done()` method on the insert chat function has completed the execution and the `.done()` completes it's execution when the mail is successfully sent from the server side. Now the sending of email takes some time. This slows down the chat retrieval by 5-10 seconds. I expected `.done()` to work in the background without disturbing other functions on the page. However, it's not working as expected.

Server Side (chat-mail.php)

```
$name  = (!empty($_POST['name']))?$_POST['name']:null;
$email = (!empty($_POST['email']))?$_POST['email']:null;
$msg   = (!empty($_POST['msg']))?$_POST['msg']:null;

if($_POST){
  $sub = $settings['site_name'].' - '.$user['name'][0].' sent you a new message';
  $message = mailHead();
  $message .= '<div class="mail-body">
                <p>Hi '.$name.'</p>
                <p><b>'.$user['name'][0].'</b> sent you a new message.</p>
                <p class="chatMessage">'.$msg.'</p>
                <p>Please open '.$settings['site_name'].' app on your phone to respond now. It\'s joyful to see that you are enjoying your stay at <b>'.$settings['site_name'].'</b>.</p>
                <p>
                  Best Wishes<br>
                  '.$settings['site_name'].' Team
                </p>
              </div>';
  $message .= mailFoot();
  // echo mailSender($sub, $message, $f['email']);
  echo mailSender($sub, $message, 'jhajinamaste@gmail.com');
}
```

chat.php

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO messages(incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg)VALUES(:imsg, :omsg, :msg)");
$stmt-> bindValue(':imsg', $imsg);
$stmt-> bindValue(':omsg', sessionUser());
$stmt-> bindValue(':msg', encrypt($chatMsg, ENCRYPTION_KEY));
$stmt-> execute();

if($stmt){
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, email, last_activity, notify_email_messages FROM users WHERE id = :imsg");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':imsg', $imsg);
  $stmt-> execute();
  $f = $stmt->fetch();

  if($f['notify_email_messages'] == 'yes' && minsDiff($f['last_activity']) >= 5){
    $status = ($f['notify_email_messages'] == 'yes' && minsDiff($f['last_activity']) >= 5)?'send':'ok';
    echo json_encode(array('name' => $f['name'], 'email' => $f['email'], 'status' => $status, 'message' => $chatMsg));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just send the email directly from `chat.php` instead of causing another round trip to the server (by sending back data which simply tells the client to make another request to the server containing information the server already knew about a few moments earlier). That should save some bandwidth. I'd guess maybe you're having issue if your PHP server only has one thread it can dedicate to your session. Your browser's network tool should tell you if requests are being queued, if you look at the graph over time

Comment: P.s. in general, websockets are a far better technology to deliver a chat app than AJAX

Comment: @ADyson does that mean AJAX is "bad" or a technology "not worth it" to use for php mysql chat apps?

Comment: Well it's bad in the sense that it's not real-time, so it will always be a few seconds before you receive a message because of the timeout. And if you try to make it real-time by shortening the timeout, you'll overload your server (and potentially also the client) with a huge number of requests. Also, AJAX generates a new HTTP request each time, which has an overhead (handshake, sending the headers etc), so that further increases use of bandwidth. AJAX is great for on-demand or infrequent async requests to the server, but inappropriate for real-time use.

Comment: By contrast, a websocket connection only needs to be opened once, and you get instant, real-time, inexpensive two-way communication between client and server - you don't have to rely on timeouts and polling from the client, because the server can directly push messages to the client through the socket whenever it wants to.

Comment: Totally understood. I need to learn how to convert my above code into websockets.